# Odds of getting the largest possible hand in blackjack

Tags: probability

My coworkers were discussing the odds of getting the largest possible blackjack hand (largest meaning the most cards possible). That hand would be the set
$$\left \{ {A, A, A, A, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3} \right\}$$

It's been a few years since I've done probability, but my thoughts are that it would be something like this.

Assuming that you are dealt first and it is a two person game, you need to get one of twelve (because you could get 3 of the 4 threes) cards in the (full) deck. Then you need to get one of eleven in the deck (minus one), which is an unrelated event... etc.

$$
\frac{12}{52} \times \frac{11}{51} \times \frac{10}{50} \times \frac{9}{49} \times \frac{8}{48} \times \frac{7}{47} \times \frac{6}{46} \times \frac{5}{45} \times \frac{4}{44} \times \frac{3}{43} \times \frac{2}{42} $$

which (I think) reduces to
$$\frac{12!}{(52! - 41!)}$$

Am I thinking about this the right way? How do I compensate for the fact that you must get 3 threes and not four (it is not a true set of 12 that you could need at the beginning)? Are there any other considerations that I need to make for the other players being dealt cards?

Comment: Close; it is actually $\dfrac{11!41!}{52!}$. You want the factors of $51!$ less than 42 to all cancel, so you must use division, not subtraction.

Comment: @AEdwards ok, my college math teachers won't be quite as disappointed in me - not too horrible for taking that course 4 years ago. I edited my question to account for getting 3 of 4 threes, but that's still tripping me up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are $\binom{52}{11}$ ways that you can choose $11$ cards out of $52$. Now, which hands you are interested in: It should contain $4$ aces, $4$ twos and $3$ threes. There are $\binom{4}{3}$ ways that you can choose the threes. So, at the end, we are interested in $\binom{4}{3}$ hands out of the total $\binom{52}{11}$. The probability will be $$\binom{4}{3}/\binom{52}{11} = 4\frac{11!41!}{52!}$$

Comment: Just publicizing my support for this answer. This is (in my opinion) the proper way to think about these types of discrete combinatorial problems.

Answer (score 1):

Almost - but you need 11!*41!/52!

Comment: @AEdwards, beat me to it by seconds :)

Comment: This does not count the possible combinations of the $3$ threes.