# Odds of winning a blackjack hand with 5 or more cards

Tags: probability, combinations, gambling

In Red Dead Redemption 2 there is a challenge to win 3 hands of blackjack while hitting 3 or more times. I'm trying to calculate the probability of this happening on any given hand.

So far using a helpful script from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39178939/9044877 I've been able to find the number of possible winning hands at each number of cards to be this:

```
11: 4
10: 432
9:  5164
8:  22320
7:  48356
6:  58480
5:  38492
4:  12704
3:  2036
2:  64
```

I'm pretty sure the next step is figuring out the total number of possible combinations for each number of cards similar to how it is done here: [Odds of getting the largest possible hand in blackjack](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/471536/odds-of-getting-the-largest-possible-hand-in-blackjack) and then calculate the odds for each number of cards, then add them up.

The issue with this (I think) is that it doesn't take into account that it doesn't take into account that you would be bust on certain scenarios. To find the number of ways to organize 52 cards into 11 spots you use $\binom{52}{11}$, but this disregards that if you got say 3 kings on your first 3 cards you wouldn't be able to go further.

Is there an intuitive way to solve this that I'm missing?

Comment: @hardmath Updated the title, thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for an analytical answer or a numerical answer?

Comment: It might help to know in some detail what kind of "stopping" rule you have in mind for a player to use here. For example, no sane person would ask for another card if they have blackjack (e.g., an Ace and a Jack) to begin with, but someone wanting to get a five-card "win" might justify it (hoping they'll get three more cards that add up to $9$), and I don't think the rules disallow it (except for the dealer, who has no choice on when to hit and when to stand).